# vector of Objects having pointer of Object

Tags: c++, c, vector, structure, pointer-to-array

Quick question guys, I have the following issue:

I have an Object (struct) pointer in my code, and when I modify something, to keep track of its history, I'm saving it in a vector (stack) of Objects.
So I'm trying to do.

```
{
   Object* myObject;
   vector<Object> stack;


   stuffHappensInObject(*myObject);
   stack.push_back(myObject);

   if(IclickLoadLast){
    myObject = stack.at(size-1);
   }
}
```

I'm having a problem with the `push_back` call and I don't know if its possible to get ALL the struct variables in a new Object into the stack. How can I do that?

Comment: And the question is...?

Comment: What is the problem exactly? The only issue I see is that of dereferencing the uninitialized pointer `myObject` when you call `stuffHappensInObject()`

Comment: @Jefffrey Implicit in the comment: `push_back` isn't working.

Comment: What does it mean it isn't working?

Comment: @anthony-arnold Well, the `vector` contains `Object`s, and not `Object *`s, so you'll need to dereference when you `push_back` ... `stack.push_back(*myObject);`. But my earlier comment still stands if this is really what your code is doing.

Comment: Show us your real code please.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use pointers in the first place, there is not need here. The problem was caused by the fact that you were trying to add a `Object*` to a vector of `Object` (not to mention the fast-ticket to UB-land when dereferencing an uninitialized pointer). Here's the fixed code:

```
{
    Object myObject;
    std::vector<Object> stack;


    stuffHappensInObject(myObject);
    stack.push_back(myObject);

    if(IclickLoadLast){
        myObject = stack.at(stack.size() - 1);
    }
}
```

I've also changed `size` to `stack.size()` which is a valid method of `std::vector` that you can use. Also, take a look at [`std::stack`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack) which provides more stack-like operations:

```
{
    Object myObject;
    std::stack stack;


    stuffHappensInObject(myObject);
    stack.push(myObject);

    if(IclickLoadLast){
        myObject = stack.top();
    }
}
```

In both cases, if you are using C++11, I suggest you to use `std::vector::emplace_back` or `std::stack::emplace` instead of `push_back` and `push`.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of issues:

This will not work:

```
stack.push_back(myObject);
```

because `myObject` has a type of `Object*` while the stack takes of objects of type `Object`. Please notice the slight difference in type. I am not sure why you are even using pointers (not enough context).

But there is another major problem:
Here you de-reference an uninitialized pointer. The result is **undefined behavior**.

```
Object* myObject;                  // No value defined (so it is random)
stuffHappensInObject(*myObject);   // De-referencing (the *) on an uninitialized pointer.
```

Comment: +1 (hope the corrections are appropriate, minor that they are).